# Object not inheretinting functions from super class?

Tags: python, class, object, spyder

So I keep getting the

> error: " AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'"

The thing is `print(spot.get_name())` works fine. Also when I tried `spot.multiple_sounds()` that fails similarly. I think the issue is when I try to call object attributes from the super class in functions in object definition. I can't understand why though. I'm doing all this from a tutorial and the code is identical to his. I think it may be because he's using python2.x and I'm using spyder python3.x but I have no idea. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import random
import os
import sys

class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self,name,height,weight,sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return(self.__name)

    def set_height(self, height):
        self.__height = height

    def get_height(self):
        return(self.__height)

    def set_weight(self, weight):
        self.__weight = weight

    def get_weight(self):
        return(self.__weight)

    def set_sound(self, sound):
        self.__sound = sound

    def get_sound(self):
        return(self.__sound)

    def get_type(self):
        print("animal")

    def toString(self):
        return("{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                        self.__height,
                                                                        self.__weight,
                                                                        self.__sound))


cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10,'Meow')

print(cat.toString())

class Dog(Animal):

    __owner = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super().__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def set_owner(self,owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_type(self):
        print("Dog")

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms says {} and his owner is {}".format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound, self.__owner)

    def multiple_sounds(self, how_many=None):
        if how_many is None:
            print(self.getsound())
        else:
            print(self.getsound()*how_many)

spot = Dog("Spot", 53, 27, "Ruff", "Some Guy")
print(spot.get_name())
print(spot.toString())
```

Comment: Smaller examples are better... you could trim most of that out into a sample program that is easier to read but demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @e4c5 - I don't think that's close enough for a dup. It is talking mainly about special methods like `__init__`.

Comment: ok @tdelaney retracting

Answer (score 2):

In python, `__fieldName` emulates the private field, means two underscores that in field name. So such fields can not be reached from derived classes, but you still can get them using getter.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the double underscore from all variables and it worked, but how would I use getter to call them?

Comment: self.get_name(), if you need a private variable in child class, your getter is public

Answer (score 1):

Any attribute or method that begins with '__' is *only* accessible by that name from functions in that same class. Not from other classes, not even from subclasses.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

class B(A):
    def get_name_capitalized(self):
        return self.__name.upper()

b = B('Bob')
print(b.get_name())  # prints 'Bob'
print(b.get_name_capitalized()) # fails
```

In the code above, calling `A.get_name()` accesses the A instance's `__name` attribute successfully.  But `B.get_name_capitalized()` fails with the error "AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__name'
". "__" names get mangled by the compiler so that they are not accessible as-is. If the code in `get_name_capitalized` is changed to:

```
    return self._A__name.upper()
```

then it would work, so these attributes *are* accessible, but you have to use the mangled name to get at them.

That is how Python has been since 1.x, and is nothing new with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Names that begin with double-underscores and end with zero or 1 underscore are python's answer to private variables. Python munges them to be `__Class_name` to make them private to the class and not its inherited subclasses. The idea is to let you have intra-class names without subclasses messing with them. Obviously this is easily subverted by using the well-known munged name, but then, python is a dynamic language.

See [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)